# Can't change label.text and don't know why

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

I want to change `label.text` but when I do it and check it with a `NSLog` it returns me a `(null)`.

Here's my code:

`NextViewController.h`

```
    @interface NextViewController (){
    NSTimer *timerTen;
    NSInteger countDown;
    NSString *timer;
}

@end

@implementation NextViewController
static UILabel *lblTest;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

-(void)startCountDown{
    countDown = 10;
    timerTen = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(dismissView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
-(void)dismissView{
    timer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)countDown];
    _lbl_countDown.text = timer;
    NSLog(@"\nCountDown: %@\n", self.lbl_countDown.text);
    countDown--;
    if (countDown <= 0) {
        SectionViewController *sectionView = [[SectionViewController alloc] init];
        [sectionView.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Then I have a XIB file with a label and more things, so I've used a prop right there in the .h to change it from other classes, but I can't change it.

`NextViewController.h`

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NextViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_section;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_nextSection;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_countDown;

-(void)startCountDown;
@end
```

Hope anyone can help me cause I don't know what is happening here.

Thanks.

Comment: You should add timer to main run loop: [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer: timerTen forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

Comment: where do you call startCountDown method?\

Comment: Updating the interface should be done on the main thread, so be sure that either dismissView is being called on the main thread or call one of the performSelectorOnMainThread:… variants to set the text.

Answer (score 0):

Call your method in ViewDidLoad  or ViewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

     [self startCountDown]
}
```

**OR**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];

     [self startCountDown]
}
```

Comment: The trick is that im calling this function from other class and i don't want to call it in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: What exactly you want and which text do you want to set to label and when ?

Comment: i want to change an UILabel from another view, just this, and I want only want to change the label text without calling `[self presentVieController:View animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: view.yourLabel.text = @"Set text here"; add before [self presentVieController:View animated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the function first using `[self startCountDown]` in the `ViewDidLoad` method

if the problem persist:

- Try to use this : `[_lbl_count setText@"myText"];`
- In the Identity Inspector, click on the label uncheck the **'Static Text'** and check **'Enabled'** and **'User Interaction Enabled'**
- Finally check that your variable `timer` is not null after your initialization.

  `timer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)countDown];`

Hope that will be helpfull

Comment: Variable `timer` is not null, that's why i don't know why I cant set the label. And I've used `[_lbl_count setText@"myText"];`and is not working, but thanks :S

Comment: Why u don't use `timer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", countDown];`

Comment: Its what i've used, timer is an integer, but then when i use it on label its null :S

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code to use a button tap to start a countdown from 10 to a segue:

In my h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *countdownCounter;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *countdownStarter;
```

In my m:

```
static NSTimer *timer;
static int remainingCounts;
.
.
-(void)countDown 
{
  if (--remainingCounts == 0)
  {
    [timer invalidate];
     timer = nil;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FromStartToBalancer" sender:self];
  }
  else
  {
    NSString * holdText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", remainingCounts];
    [self.countdownCounter setText:holdText];
  }
}

- (IBAction)goToBalancerPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
  self.countdownStarter.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  self.countdownStarter.alpha = .3;
  remainingCounts = 10;
  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(countDown)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];  
}
```